# Reference Recommendation: Generalization of Dunford-Pettis in Various Settings

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request

I have been coming across with Dunford-Pettis quite a bit recently. I have found Banach Lattice offers quite some generalization, and there are some nice things about Dunford-Pettis on Mackey topology. However, I wonder whether there are some more excellent results, or even better, a monograph dedicated to this topic. In the meantime, any applications would also be better.

Thanks a lot.